# Destination value with DirectionsRenderer in Google Maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Loving Google Maps API V3, but having difficulty in getting accurate driving directions *and* manipulating the destination address displayed when using [DirectionsRenderer](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#DirectionsRenderer).

Regardless if I pass an address string or a [latLng](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#LatLng) instance as the destination to [DirectionsService](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#DirectionsService), when I use the `DirectionsRenderer` to output step-by-step directions, the destination text is always the geocoded result of my original destination (i.e. the address, rather than COMPANY NAME).

Ideally, I want to pass a precise `latLng` destination to `DirectionsService`, but control the text displayed as the 'destination'.

I guess I could manually output the HTML, but part lazy, part not wanting to re-invent the wheel, would prefer to use `DirectionsRenderer`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use:

```
response.routes[0].legs[0].end_address="Company";
```

before calling

```
directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
```